# When the keys are used

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure that I understand when keys are used in mongo Db.

In This Example

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.fubar",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.fubar",
        "name" : "a_1_b_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "c" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.fubar",
        "name" : "a_1_c_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "c" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "test.fubar",
        "name" : "c_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1,
            "c" : -1
        },
        "ns" : "test.fubar",
        "name" : "a_1_b_1_c_-1"
    }
]
```

In this Query

```
db.fubar.find({'a':{'$lt':10000}, 'b':{'$gt': 5000}}, {'a':1, 'c':1}).sort({'c':-1})
```

I know that keys could be used

- a_1_b_1
  -a_1_c_1
- c_1
- a_1_b_1_c_-1

But Why - `a_1_b_1_c_-1` is used ?

- `a_1_b_1` used in find
- `a_1_c_1` used in Projection
- `c_1` used in sort

Where I use `a_1_b_1_c_-1` ? in Find ?

Comment: `c_-1` is used in sort not `c_1`

Comment: Where c_1 is used? in Projection ?

Comment: c_-1 would be used in the sort process, so MongoDB is picking that compound index for that reason

Comment: Wait sorry, I think I know what you mean now. Ok I had assumed you knew how indexes in MongoDB work. The query is using only one index you'll find if you do an explain(); it is using a_1_b_1_c_-1, and it uses that index for the whole query except for projection, if you add _id:0 to projection then it should be covered

Comment: As to why, because index inter-sectioning would be more costly than going for that single index that satisfies the entire query and its sort.

Comment: then a_1_b_1_c_-1 used in find and the best. also a_1_b_1 could bue used in find. Where use than a_1_c_1 and c_1 ? also in Find?

Comment: a_1_c_1 could be used for find and sort, but the document would need to source b, c_1 would not be used

Comment: Sorry, a_1_c_1 would not be used for sort, only find

Comment: thanks now i Understand
`a_1_b_1_c_-1` in Find and the best
`a_1_b_1` in Find
`a_1_c_1` in Find beacuse a_1 is the prefix
`c_1` in Sort (reverse)

Comment: Yep your starting to get it now :) Oh c_1 can be reserved, I forgot about that, c_1 can be used since single field indexes can be reversed of course

Comment: Only single field indexes can be reserved? :)

Comment: Indeed, there are of course multiple complications to reversing compound indexes, plus they normally would not be very useful reversed, so they don't work like that

Comment: As a rule of thumb: order your indexes by exact matches, ranges, sort order, and probably lastly to have a covering index. If you have a compound index for ``a: 1, b: -1`` it can be fully used for sorting with ``a: 1, b: -1`` and ``a: -1, b: 1``, but not ``a: 1, b: 1`` or ``a: -1, b: -1``

Answer (score 0):

a_1_b_1_c_-1 can be used in the sort. This is the case where the sort subset does not start at the index beginning. Now, according to [this here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/), since the sort is happening at "c:-1", the a_1_b_1_c_-1 can only come in picture when:

- sort does not start at the index beginning (which is true)
- the query document includes all the preceding fields of the index, in this  case a and b, in equality conditions (which is also true)

Therefore, a_1_b_1_c_-1 could be used in this case.